# Why react props value is not shown?

Tags: reactjs

When i refresh the page props value is not shown. Is this possible to show props value where we left it before the refresh the page?

Code:-.

Parent component

```
const LeftNav = () => {
return (

            <div className="allDivs">
                {item.map((items, index) => {
                    //   console.log(item)

                    return (
                        <div key={index} >
                            <TabHeader item={items} index={index}/>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>

 </div >
    )
}
export default LeftNav;
```

Child componentL;-

```
export default function TabHeader({ item, index }) {
return (
        <Fragment>
            <div id="CLOSEDIV">
                <div className="TableText" onClick={(e) => { handleOnClick(e, Delete.val) }}>
                    <div id="SHOW">{Delete.val}</div>
                </div>
</div>
 </Fragment >

    )
}
```

please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refresh the page, the browser will flush all the in memory javascript and react must initialize again.

To persist data between reloads you can use the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).